# This computer currently has no detected operating systems

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to ubuntu 14.04 and I am attempting to install it on my laptop (Acer Aspire V3/772G-Intel) which already has Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I currently have two partitions on my HDD and I was planning on repartitioning my secondary partition to make room for a third to use for Ubuntu. However when I attempt to install (with DVD & USB) I get the following message:

"This computer currently has no detected operating systems"

Comment: Are you using MBR or GPT partitions?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed using the **gdisk** utility. Use the live version of Ubuntu then do the next:

```
sudo apt-get install gdisk

sudo fixparts /dev/sda
```

then press `"w"`

After doing that you should be able to install Ubuntu in the third partition.

**Source:**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/288999/ubuntu-13-04-not-detecting-windows-7-during-install